# Visual Studio 2008: String Literals "??-", "??'", "??=" corrupt

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, string-literals, character-replacement

Recently I came across a bug in **Visual Studio 2008** (at least I think it is one).

When I try to create **string-literals** with two questionmarks followed by another character, something weird occurs: Those three chars are replaced by another char.

*Examples:*

```
printf("??-"); --> ~  (hyphen)
printf("??'"); --> ^  (circumflex)
printf("??="); --> #  (hash)
printf("??)"); --> ]  (square braket)
printf("??("); --> [  (square braket)
printf("??/"); --> \  (backslash)
printf("??!"); --> |  (pipe)
printf("??%"); --> ?? (percent sign disappears)
```

Does anybody know the reason for this replacement?

Comment: Not sure with the reason but `printf(@"??-");` must work. And I know you are looking out for reasons than solutions. But just pointing out so it helps someone

Comment: I think you can avoid these replacements by using `\?` instead of the plain `?`.

Comment: The last one is "normal" behaviour - to `printf` a `%` you need `%%` in the format string.

Comment: @Reddy: No, printf(@"??-") doesn't work with VS2008 & C++

Comment: This was a good question. +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's no bug, more a hangover of history. They're C trigraphs - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bt0y4awe.aspx

Di/Tri-graphs are a way to represent characters that weren't easily available back when the language was developed. They let you enter symbols into your source code that you may not have a keyboard key to represent.

```
Tri-graph Symbol
??=       #
??/       \
??'       ^
??(       [
??)       ]
??!       |
??<       {
??>       }
??-       ~
```

The % issue is just the usual one in printf where you need to escape a % with a % if you wish to see it. This is because the % is usually the beginning of a format specifier.

Comment: Never heard of "Tri-graph". Thanks!

Comment: A useful workaround would be to split the Tri-graph after the two questionmarks:
`printf("??" "-")`.

This definitely works :)

Comment: You can usually turn them off in most compilers. This means your code does not strictly conform to the standard, but it's rare anyone actually wants a di/trigraph these days.

Comment: They're already removed from the draft for the next Standard (C++17), so it makes sens for modern compilers to drop the feature. VS2008 of course isn't C++17-aware ;)